# Show time only of datetime field in edit form of external list

Tags: external-list, edit-form

I have an external list containing a datetime column called "Opening". I would like to show only the time portion of this column in all views (list, edit etc.). I know how to do this in the list view, by use of the "edit formula" in sharepoint designer (design view). Is this also possible in the one-item-views? There seems to be no "edit formula" available here.
I tried to change the form field to datetimefield as follows:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeField TimeOnly="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Opening" IncludeDescription="True"></SharePoint:DateTimeField>
```

but despite of TimeOnly="true", the date portion is still shown. Is customizing of the forms possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by manipulating the xpath expression of the fields and using javascript as shown in this [article](http://blog.allegient.com/blog/csi-code-crib/suppressing-time-information-in-sharepoint-2010-bcs-external-lists).

Answer (score 0):

Customizing the form is one aspect - that happens in the list already (unless you do provision your Forms with your solution), but I believe you are looking at doing it declaratively. 
There is no way as exposed to do it declaratively as only Date is supported, but you could opt for creating a calculated column that uses any of the formulas as exposed here http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2009/05/02/common-date-time-formulas-for-sharepoint-calculated-fields/ - the downside is that it is Read-Only.

My take: If you want to "Edit" it either go for customizing the Edit forms or programatically go for a Custom field.

Comment: Hi C. Marius, do you mean by "customizing the Edit forms" to create a new edit form in sharepoint designer?

Comment: Indeed. Greater flexibility is gained, e.g. all functions to process DateTime available in the ddwrt library, XSLT, and many more